# How to edit a JTree node with a single-click

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree`, and would like for its `getTreeCellEditorComponent()` method to be invoked when I single click on a node.  According to the documentation for the `DefaultTreeCellEditor` class (which I extended), "Editing is started on a triple mouse click, or after a click, pause, click and a delay of 1200 miliseconds."  Is there some way to override this behavior, so that a single-click could start the editing process?

Comment: hmm ... you might re-consider the usability of a single click: that's the trigger to un/selection

Answer (score 6):

The [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) API recommends a `MouseListener`, but a key binding is also handy. This example invokes `startEditingAtPath()` and binds to the Enter key:

```
final JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setEditable(true);
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int row = tree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (row != -1) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                tree.startEditingAtPath(path);
            }
        }
    }
};
tree.addMouseListener(ml);
tree.getInputMap().put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "startEditing");
```

Addendum: See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637927/230513) regarding usability.

Comment: Only possible by learning from [top contributors like you!](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers).

Comment: >100k (congrats, of course :-) or not: this is not an answer to the question <ducking> and jtree already _has_ a binding (to F2 if I remember correctly)

Comment: @kleopatra: Right about `F2` on most platforms, but not `AquaLookAndFeel`.

Comment: ... so it has no binding to start edit at all? Interesting, item to insert into local knowledgebase :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: Yes. As far as I can tell, `JTree` for `AquaLookAndFeel` has only the two mouse click gestures mentioned in the question. Would invoking `startEditingAtPath()` in a `MouseListener` be an alternative?

Comment: curious: why looking for an alternative - doesn's my answer work on mac?

Comment: @kleopatra: Perfectly; just looking to improve this answer.

Comment: adding a kludge couldn't really improve it :-) see @mKorbel's comment on my answer: the referenced link does the startEditingPath (though in a selectionListener), it is possible but by-passes api designed to get it working - which is not the best of ideas, IMO

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you can subclass DefaultTreeCellEditor and tweaks its logic to start editing on the first single click:

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setEditable(true);
TreeCellEditor editor = 
        new DefaultTreeCellEditor(tree, (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) tree.getCellRenderer()) {
    @Override
    protected boolean canEditImmediately(EventObject event) {
        if((event instanceof MouseEvent) &&
           SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton((MouseEvent)event)) {
            MouseEvent       me = (MouseEvent)event;

            return ((me.getClickCount() >= 1) &&
                    inHitRegion(me.getX(), me.getY()));
        }
        return (event == null);
    }
};
tree.setCellEditor(editor);
```

There's a usability quirk, though, as now you can't select without starting an edit - which may or may not be your intention.

Comment: maybe not [see post by @Michael Dunn](http://www.coderanch.com/t/584508/GUI/java/change-DefaultCellEditor-setClickCountToStart-int-DefaultTreeCellEditor)

Comment: @mKorbel  I'm a bit weary of by-passing the editor api and manually starting the edit. Anyway, the row _is selected_ only it feels a bit unusual to not being able to select without editing ..

Comment: question is like it is, I'm doubt that your good sugestion, with clear concept will be accepted ...