# JTree with tabbed panel as tree node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree in swing. The tree nodes should contain panel with tabs. The tabs should contain textarea with scrollpane. The problem is I am able to add panel with tabs in the tree node but the problem is I can't go from one tab to another. It seems the panel is disabled. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance. Below is my code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class ModifiedTreePanel  
{  
    Random seed;  

    public ModifiedTreePanel()  
    {  
        seed = new Random();  

        // south section  
        final JLabel colorLabel = new JLabel();  
        colorLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);  
        Dimension d = colorLabel.getPreferredSize();  
        d.height = 25;  
        colorLabel.setPreferredSize(d);  

        // center section  
        JTree tree = createTree();  
        tree.setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer(tree));
        tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(  
                                         new TreeSelectionListener()  
        {  
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e)  
            {  

            }  
        });  

        JFrame f = new JFrame();  
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        f.add(new JScrollPane(tree));  
        f.add(colorLabel, "South");  
        f.setSize(400,400);  
        f.setLocation(200,200);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }  

    protected JComponent createTabbedPanel (String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", panel1);
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", panel2);

        JComponent panel3 = makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", panel3);

        panel.add(tabbedPane);
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);

        panel.setEnabled(true);
        return panel;
    }

    protected JComponent makeTextPanel (String text) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
            JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
            filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            panel.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,1));
            panel.add(filler);
            return panel;
    }

    private JTree createTree()  
    {  
        int children = 4;  
        int grandChildren = 1;  

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node;  
        for(int j = 0; j < children; j++)  
        {  
            node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child-"+String.valueOf(j));

            root.add(node);  
                for(int k = 0; k < grandChildren; k++)  
                    node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(createTabbedPanel("Grand-" + String.valueOf(k))));  
        }  
        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);  
        return new JTree(model);  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        new ModifiedTreePanel();  
    }  
}  

class CustomRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor 
    implements TreeCellRenderer, TreeCellEditor  
{     

    final JTree tree;

    public CustomRenderer (JTree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }


    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,  
                                                  Object value,  
                                                  boolean selected,  
                                                  boolean expanded,  
                                                  boolean leaf,  
                                                  int row,  
                                                  boolean hasFocus)  
    {  
        Object nodeObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).getUserObject();
        if (nodeObject instanceof JPanel){
            JPanel panel = (JPanel) nodeObject;    
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100)); 
            return panel;
        } else{
            return new JLabel(nodeObject.toString());
        }

    }

    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(
            JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected,
            boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
        return getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                tree, value, true, expanded, leaf, row, true);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(final EventObject event) {
        if (!(event instanceof MouseEvent)) {
            return false;
        }

        final MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
        final TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(
                mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
        if (path == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Object node = path.getLastPathComponent();
        if (node == null || (!(node instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode))) {
            return false;
        }

        DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node;
        Object userObject = treeNode.getUserObject();

        return (userObject instanceof JPanel);
    }


    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Cell renderers are "snap shots" and aren't real live components.

Comment: start applying your learning (of mad's references) by _not_ storing components in your node: instead store the data and let the renderer/editor do their jobs

Answer (score 2):

Cell renderers are "snap shots" and aren't real live components

See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

You have to provide a custom editor for the node and build it's content each time the editor is activated based on the content of the original node.

What you shouldn't be doing is using components as the node's `userObject` property, but rather passing information to the node that can be used by both the renderer and editor to construct their individual views.

Take a look at:

- [easy and fast JTree Cell Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642792/easy-and-fast-jtree-cell-editor)
- [How to edit a JTree node with a single-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625424/how-to-edit-a-jtree-node-with-a-single-click)

For some examples...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please edit my posted code with the changes?

Comment: @pintu _Can you please edit my posted code with the changes_ Certainly he could, but most probably wouldn't (except when you hire him as your consultant maybe ;-) - it's your job to understand the references, nothing much anybody else can do to help you. Without such understanding, the code wouldn't help much because next time around you again wouldn't be able to solve a similar problem. So try to apply them yourself and come back when you are stuck, explaining where exactly you experience a problem

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for your suggestion. I asked for an example over my posted code. It seemed to me little complex as I am a beginner to programming java swing and the node also contains a component that is complex too. And sure I will try and if come up with a problem I will come to you.